# Add value in NULL column

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

How to add value to a cell of column in pandas Excel? The data in Excel is coming from a database.

The last column of my sheet is null in database I want to add manually a value to that column.

```
c.execute('select * from employee where id = (?);', (ids,))
result2 = c.fetchall()

today = str(date.today())

data = pd.DataFrame(result2, columns= ['id', 'Employee Name','Employee ID', 
                                       'Department', 'Attendance'])
datatoexcel = pd.ExcelWriter("Employee Attendance"+today+".xlsx", 
                             engine='xlsxwriter')
data.to_excel(datatoexcel, index=False, sheet_name = "Sheet")

worksheet = datatoexcel.sheets['Sheet']
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 7)
worksheet.set_column('B:B', 20)
worksheet.set_column('C:C', 20)
worksheet.set_column('D:D', 30)
worksheet.set_column('E:E', 20)

datatoexcel.save()
```

Comment: check out `df.fillna()` if you want help you need to provide [mcve]

Comment: Please show data of current results and desired results. Text is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approaches.

- Change the sql to select by column name and use a `CASE` statement or a constant instead of the actual last column (remember to alias a name for it).
- Add an iterator over result2 to populate the last column before it is processed further.